# Laravel 5.8 Developing Auth With Custom Table and Fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-5.8

I am creating a Laravel 5.8 app and I have an existing app with its users registered in a SQL table. I am able to connect to sql so the .env files are correct but I need custom fields in the Auth process. I have checked online guides but a lot seems to have changed from the 5.6 or older versions used in the guides to the 5.8. Can anyone help me out in figuring out first how to change the username field to 'username' instead of 'email', I already tried overriding the function in app\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php but this just keeps saying "These credentials do not match our records." in the errors section. My current table called 'users_custom' contains the following fields:

- id (UNIQUE, int(5))
- username (varchar(100))
- password (varchar(100)) Note: This is an older md5 encoded password. I need help with the hash format of Laravel as well without needing users to re-enter their passwords if possible.
- passphrase (varchar(200)) //This was made for DialogFlow in an earlier version. This need not be accessed/checked by laravel.

My app doesn't work on the user's email so that field is not present in my users table. I defined `protected $table='users_custom';` in the Users model.

**EDIT: Solved**

Not sure how but when I started afresh with the default Auth controllers and User model, I just changed the table name as `protected $table = users_custom` and I added `public function username() { return 'username'; }` in LoginController and it works now.

Comment: You have to define the database column to be used for login in the LoginController instead of User.php

Comment: Sorry, corrected that. I did add it in LoginController not in User model.

Comment: Does your login work now ?

Comment: Nope. I mean to say I had done that earlier, I just described it wrong. Even now, I just get the same old "These credentials do not match our records."

Comment: Add this method to the top of the logincontroller and also dd(request()->all()) in the login controller to make sure the data being passed to the controller is as you expect it to be from clientside.  Make sure you add this method after AuthenticatesUsers trait   public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

Comment: Alright, I moved the method below the AuthenticatesUsers now. And the 'dd($request->all())' , where should this go in the login controller?

Answer (score -3):

In config/auth.php change 'table' => 'users' to 'table' => 'custom_user'

and create migration for accounts

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: `config/auth.php` do nothing on migration